# Excel - Return multiple matching values from a column, horizontally in one row

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

I have an excel formula, which is supposed to work but returns #VALUE and I cannot figure out why.

I have this table:

```
       A        B
1 |          |     |
2 | Oranges  |  1  |
3 | Apples   |  2  |
4 | Grapes   |  3  |
5 | Oranges  |  4  |
6 | Apples   |  5  |
7 | Grapes   |  6  |
8 | Apples   |  7  |
```

I want to Check for matching values in Column A like "Apples", "Oranges", etc. and return all the corresponding values from Column B in one row:

The output should be like this but I only get #VALUE:

```
       A         B     C     D  
11 | Apples   |  2  |  5  |  7  |
12 | Oranges  |  1  |  4  | #NUM|
```

This is the formula:

> =INDEX($B$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF($A$11=$A$2:$A$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1), COLUMN(A1)))

Comment: This is an array formula. To enter a formula as an array formula, type the formula in the cell and press the CTRL SHIFT and ENTER keys at the same time rather then just ENTER.

Comment: This was the solution! Thank you very much! You can have it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this formula help you.. you need to press Ctrl + shift + enter to get the formula working, you need to order the PRODUCT column by name to get the formula working properly.

```
=IF(COLUMN()-4<=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,$D2),INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH($D2,$A$2:$A$8,0)+COLUMN()-5),"")
```

the -4 is referencing the column where you are going to lookup the value and the -5 is where you are going to get the value.

The column "c" is empty

```
COL    A         B          C         D           E       F        G      H
    PRODUCT  DESCRIPTION         uniquevalues  descr1   descr2  descr3  descr4
    oranges      1                 oranges        1       2     
    oranges      2                 apples         3       4        5    
    grapes       6                 grapes         6       7     
    grapes       7                      
    apples       3                      
    apples       4                      
    apples       5
```

I hope it is not too late :P.. you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid #NUM error use this modified formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$11=$A$2:$A$8,ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```