# How to find the LOCATION of the K'th largest value of a range in Excel?

Tags: excel

The question is as in the title. Note that `LARGE(range, k)` doesn't tell me the location of the value, and attempting to search for it using `INDEX` can fail in the presence of duplicates. Is there another way?

Comment: "search for it using INDEX can fail in the presence of duplicates" so you want all locations?

Comment: The solution would be to use LARGE(range, k) and a combination of any number of 'return multiple results' methods which can be found on SO. For example, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424226/excel-return-multiple-matching-values-from-a-column-horizontally-in-one-row

Comment: @RC.: Not *all* of them, but I need distinct locations for distinct k.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the original data and whether you're in a position to modify the workbook, one way is to use a "helper column" to give you unique values by adding a very small row-dependent value to your data, eg the row number divided by 1000000. As long as the additional value isn't greater than the smallest true difference in data values it will not change the rank ordering of the data, but it does make it unique and has the benefit of being relatively "easy".

[image: screenshot from an Excel spreadsheet demonstrating this technique]

In this example B3:B17 contains mostly integer values, a couple of ".5" fractions, with some duplication. I have set C3:C17 as the helper column, in which I'm adding and adjustment value of the row number * 0.0000001. As the smallest step change in the genuine data is much larger than the largest adjustment value, there is no risk of incorrect ordering - only an imposition that where the original data is exactly the same, ordering is now based on location in the table.

Column F lists the largest helper values (eg cell F3 formula `"=LARGE($C$3:$C$17,E3)"`), column G finds the row that value is in (cell G3 formula `"=MATCH(F3,C:C,0)"`), and then your output table looks in the genuine data using this row number.

Comment: This is a clever hack but are you basically saying there isn't another solution?

Comment: No, but it has the benefit of being easy to implement where there's no risk that the "rank adjustment" is greater than the required precision in the data.

This is really two problems in one - determining unique ranking from non-unique data, then determining the locations.

There are other approaches to the first part of the problem which don't require helper columns, eg see Chip Pearson's site [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Rank.aspx), but you still need to tackle the locations, and I suspect that's the awkward part.

Answer (score -1):

what if you use one column and type`=IFERROR(RANG.eq(K2;"range of K")+SUMPRODUCT(--(K2=K$2:K$74"ex");--(K2<K$2:K$74));"")` and one column `=IFERROR(COUNTIFS(M2"new column":$M$74;M2)+M2-1;"")`.
After that all numbers in K will be ranged *even if equal* and you can use `LARGE`