# Looping Vlookup with INDEX

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to write an excel function/combination of functions that will loop without the use of macros.

I have one table with two columns and another table with 4 columns. The only important columns are the first two.

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

I need a function that searches through the first column of the top table and finds all materials on line 51. Material codes that are on rows with line numbers that match 51 will then be placed into the line 51 table below the first table.

NB: the first table (the one with data) will most likely never be sorted so I can not make my life easier via sorting... This first table will also be changing as it is fed from an add in excel program. I must not use macros/VBA as it needs to be sustainable for the average excel user to comprehend. I've tried nested IFs inside VLOOKUPS and many combinations of formulas, I am thinking INDEX is the way to go but I can't find a way to use INDEX to reach my desired goal.

**Even though the Line column contains some multi-lines ex 8/9, these will be non-factors as my formula should only look for a specific line, 51.

Comment: How much data are we talking?  This is going to take array formulas and the calculate exponentially at some point there will be too much and excel will crash.

Comment: http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29021549/1693085 - Not your final solution, but should get you pointed in the right direction....

Comment: @ScottCraner I anticipate at most 300 rows in the first table that the formula would have to look through to find roughly 50 data points to populate into the new table. Too much you think?

Comment: @JohnBustos Thanks John, at first glance it looks like that has a general structure of where I want to go. I'll run with that and see if I can come up with something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This formula should work:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G2,$A$2:$A$6))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

It is an array formula so limit the reference range to the extents of the dataset.

[image]

Comment: I subbed in my appropriate values and I am only returning "" for the cell values. I'll keep looking into it but for now here is my equation in case there is something wrong here:

=IFERROR(INDEX('By ITEM Month'!$A$22:$B$300,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('By ITEM Month'!$A$22:$A$300)-1)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A16,'By ITEM Month'!$A$22:$A$300))),ROW(1:1))),"")

Comment: @ryan you need to adjust the `-1` to `-21`: `=IFERROR(INDEX('By ITEM Month'!$A$22:$B$300,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('By ITEM Month'!$A$22:$A$300)-21)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A16,'By ITEM Month'!$A$22:$A$300))),ROW(1:1))),"")`

Comment: @ryan what excel are you using?

Comment: hmm.. made the change, still getting null cell responses. I'll admit this is a particularly tricky problem I've run across, so thank you for your help! Don't want to trouble you too much. Excel 2010!

Comment: @ryan remove the `IFERROR(..,"")` part and tell me what the error is.

Comment: it is a #REF! error. I evaluated the formula (using eval formula button in formulas tab) and it throws a #VAL error on the fourth evaluation run (click evaluate 3 times then on 4th it fails)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115762/discussion-between-ryan-and-scott-craner).